# This JS works on my home PC but not when i put it online. Any idea why or how this is?

Tags: javascript, html

This JS works on my home PC but not when i put it online. Any idea why or how this is?
At bottom of html page I have

```
<!--JAVASCRIPT-->       
<script type="text/javascript" src="drawUI.js"></script>

</body>
```

in the javascript file drawUI.js I have this. I receive no error message. It's as if the javascript just gets skipped or something. I have had other javascripts running on this same website and they work just fine. I as even using the same animation code.

```
(function(){

var ShieldPMax = 2000; var ShieldPMin = 0; var ShieldP = 1750; 
var ArmorPMax = 2000; var ArmorPMin = 0; var ArmorP= 1875;
var BattPMax = 2000; var BattPMin = 0; var BattP= 1360;
var TempPMax = 990; var TempPMin = -990; var TempP= 990;
var CPUPercPMax = 100; var CPUPercPMin = 0; var CPUPercP= 75;
var CPUPMax = 4039; var CPUPMin = 0; var CPUP= 3010;

var ShieldUp = true; var ArmorUp = false; var BattUp = true; var TempUp = true; var CPUUp = false; 


var progress;
var start = null;
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
function step(timestamp) {

    if (start === null) start = timestamp;
    progress = timestamp - start;

    //ANIMATION AND TIME BASED ACTIONS GO HERE
    incrementStats();
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  //}
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);

function incrementStats(){

    if (ShieldUp === true) {++ShieldP};
    if (ShieldUp === false) {--ShieldP};
    if (ShieldP <ShieldPMin) {ShieldP = ShieldPMin, ShieldUp = true};
    if (ShieldP >ShieldPMax) {ShieldP = ShieldPMax, ShieldUp = false};
    PlayerShieldUpdateUI(ShieldP, ShieldPMax);

    if (ArmorUp === true) {++ArmorP};
    if (ArmorUp === false) {--ArmorP};
    if (ArmorP < ArmorPMin) {ArmorP =  ArmorPMin, ArmorUp = true};
    if (ArmorP >ArmorPMax) {ArmorP = ArmorPMax, ArmorUp = false};
    PlayerArmorUpdateUI(ArmorP, ArmorPMax);

    if (BattUp === true) {++BattP};
    if (BattUp === false) {--BattP};
    if (BattP <BattPMin) {BattP = BattPMin, BattUp = true};
    if (BattP >BattPMax) {BattP = BattPMax, BattUp = false};
    PlayerBattUpdateUI(BattP, BattPMax);

    if (TempUp === true) {++TempP};
    if (TempUp === false) {--TempP};
    if (TempP <TempPMin) {TempP = TempPMin, TempUp = true};
    if (TempP >TempPMax) {TempP = TempPMax, TempUp = false};
    PlayerTempUpdateUI(TempP, TempPMax);

    if (CPUUp === true) {++CPUP};
    if (CPUUp === false) {--CPUP};
    if (CPUP <CPUPMin) {CPUP = CPUPMin, CPUUp = true};
    if (CPUP >CPUPMax) {CPUP = CPUPMax, CPUUp = false};
    PlayerCPUUpdateUI(CPUP, CPUPMax);


}

function PlayerShieldUpdateUI(ShieldPoints, MaxPoints) {
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerShieldPVal").innerHTML = ShieldPoints + "/" + MaxPoints;
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerShieldBar").style.width = (ShieldPoints / MaxPoints * 225) + "px";
};

function PlayerArmorUpdateUI(ArmorPoints, MaxPoints) {
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerArmorPVal").innerHTML = ArmorPoints + "/" + MaxPoints;
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerArmorBar").style.width = (ArmorPoints / MaxPoints * 225) + "px";
};

function PlayerBattUpdateUI(BattPoints, MaxPoints) {
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerBatteryPVal").innerHTML = BattPoints + "/" + MaxPoints;
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerBatteryBar").style.width = (BattPoints / MaxPoints * 225) + "px";
};

function PlayerTempUpdateUI(TempPoints, MaxPoints) {
    var r,g,b;
    var tempTextDiv = document.getElementById("HUDPlayerTempVal");
    tempTextDiv.innerHTML = parseInt(TempPoints/10);

    if (TempPoints >0){
    //TRANSITION WHITE TO BLUE
    b = 255 - ((TempPoints/990)*255);
    r = 255 ;
    g = b;
    tempTextDiv.style.color = "rgb(" + r + ","+ g +","+ b +")";
    }else{
    //TRANSITION WHITE TO RED
    r = 255 - (((TempPoints* -1)/990)*255);
    g = r;
    b = 255;
    tempTextDiv.style.color = "rgb(" + r + ","+ g +","+ b +")";
    }
};

function PlayerCPUUpdateUI(CPUPoints, MaxPoints) {
    var barHeight, barTopPos;
    barHeight = parseInt(((CPUPoints / MaxPoints) * 100) / 100 * 112);
    barTopPos = 162 - barHeight;

    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerCPUValGHz").innerHTML = (CPUPoints / 1000) + "GHz";
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerCPUValPercent").innerHTML = parseInt((CPUPoints / MaxPoints) * 100) + "%" ;
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerCPUBar").style.height = barHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("HUDPlayerCPUBar").style.top = barTopPos + "px";
};
```

})();

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually being included? Is `drawUI.js` in the same directory as your html file?

Comment: What do you see in the console & network tabs?

Comment: are you sure the file is uploaded to the server?

Comment: Is the `drawUI.js` included in your online application? Can you provide a link to your online application?

Comment: yes drawUI.js is in the same location, I get no message in the console. can I give url so you can see for yourself? or is that against the rules? 
 Here is the link. [link](rbgrpg.com/play01.html)

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://rbgrpg.com/drawUI.js`. Exactly which browser's console are you not seeing that error in?

Comment: chrome and IE I get my css layout but no js.

Comment: So you see the problem now right? Your drawUI.js file isn't where you think it is.

Comment: Yes, I see that now in Chrome, but strange thing is that Ive just put it there myself. Several times now :/ Thanks for the support, sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the link you provided rbgrpg.com/play01.html, if you look in the browser console you will see that there is a 404 error, the file cannot be found.

You need to make sure that the drawUI.js file is in the same folder as your play01.html. If the file is already there then the issue might be permission based. You need to check the file has permission level of a minimum of 644.

Do do this on a unix-like server assuming you can ssh into the console you could try running

```
chmod 0664 drawUI.js
```

or if you are using a GUI ftp client try right clicking the file and in most editors you will see an options for file permissions, check them there.

Comment: It happens, don't be embarrassed. Glad it is sorted.